# android + google map API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, compiler-errors

i am creating a simple app with google map api v2 but i get a problem after i add the google play services to the project it display a red exclamation mark  and in the **android build path** it show me that the **google play services-lib.jar is missing**  how to solve and fix this problem can anyone help me ?????

## android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemapv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="your.application.package.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API KEY" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemapv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## mainActivity.java

```
package com.example.googlemapv2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

## main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        class="android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: goto android project properties -> android -> select google api instead of Android 4.2

Comment: i selected google api  but still get the same problem

Comment: Once *Restart* your eclipse then clean and *Run it*.

Comment: @ RobinHood thank you for this comment it start the run process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `lib` is present in eclipse and marked as `IsLibrary` and you added `lib` in your project clicking right>project property> click `android` and add `lib`

If you done with above steps and even though you faced issue then once *Restart* your eclipse then clean and  then *Run it*.